# Check if file is executable using PowerShell on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, powershell, filesystems, executable

I don't want to use bash.

I've looked for any parameter in the `FileInfo` object, but there isn't something that tells you if the file is executable.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard [`test` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/test.1.html) (`/usr/bin/test` on Ubuntu):

```bash
$isExecutable = $(test -x '/path/to/some/file'; 0 -eq $LASTEXITCODE)
```

Note: One would expect that using `Get-Command` with a file path would indicate whether the target file is executable, but that is *not* reliable as of PowerShell 7.0: *any* existing file - whether executable or not - is currently reported as a command (of type `Application`) - see [GitHub issue #12625](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12625)

```bash
# !! SHOULD work, but does NOT as of PowerShell 7.0:
# !! any existing file is reported as executable.
$isExecutable = [bool] (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore '/path/to/some/file')
```

Note: Should this ever be fixed, note that you'll always need to specify a *path* rather than a mere file name, even for files in the current location, e.g., `Get-Command ./foo` rather than `Get-Command foo`, because the latter would only look for an `foo` executable in the directories listed in `$env:PATH`.